# NetLogo: How do I use random-gamma and division for the same calculation formula without any error?

Tags: netlogo, division, gamma

I am using random-gamma with NetLogo. When I add division to the syntax of random-gamma, NetLogo gets an error. The following is an example of calculation syntax using random-gamma. (In addition, these variables "number-dead, S, T" are registered in global variables.) In my simulation it is necessary to add division after random-gamma calculation result. What should I do? Please give some advice to this. We thank you for your cooperation.

```
set sim precision((number-dead * random-gamma(1 / (S * S))(1 / (T * (S * S)))) / number-dead)3
```

The following is a popup message when an error occurs.

`It is divided by 0.
 error while observer running /
 called by procedure GOPARALLEL
 called by button 'goparallel'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with `random-gamma`. Either `S`, `T`, or `number-dead` are likely to be 0.

If `S` is 0, then both `(1 / (S * S))` and `(1 / (T * (S * S)))` will result in division by 0.

If `T` is 0, then `(1 / (T * (S * S)))` will result in a division by 0.

If `number-dead` is 0, then `(number-dead * random-gamma (1 / (S * S)) (1 / (T * (S * S)))) / number-dead)` will result in a division by 0.

Also,  I think that code is wrong. It's essentially doing:

```
let rand random-gamma (1 / (S * S)) (1 / (T * (S * S)))
let raw-num number-dead * rand / number-dead
set sim precision raw-num 3
```

That is, you're multiplying the result of `random-gamma` by `number-dead`, and then immediately dividing the result of that by `number-dead`, which just leaves you with the result of `random-gamma`. So I think you may have misplaced some parentheses or something.

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice. I will test it with the code later. Probably it is okay. I might ask you again if I do not understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, I tested it with the recommended code, but the same error has been appeared. "It is divided by 0.". I will think about a bit more.

Comment: I didn't recommend any code... I was showing how the code you wrote is probably wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your pointing out. After that, I am still under review. I will make a new question by combining it with other questions.